# How do I serve static files from either gunicorn or nginx

Tags: django, nginx, docker

I am playing with a docker project.  Django+gunicorn in one container, nginx in another container.

When I switched over from the Django dev server to gunicorn, I noticed that all my static files weren't being served.  I've been trying to troubleshoot this for days thinking it was an nginx issue, but if I visit the container of Django/gunicorn (and not nginx), I also don't see static files showing up here, so this makes me think it is not an nginx issue but just a simple error in my Django settings?

Django settings.py

```
DEBUG = False
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "static1")
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "static"),
]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]
```

nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.org;
    charset utf-8;

    location /static {
        alias /root/proj/proj/static;
    }
}
```

Note: I set this alias to /root/proj/proj/static, because this is the directory path to where static files are actually located inside the Django/gunicorn container...  Am I correct in setting the alias to this path?

docker-compose

```
parentserver:
  build: ./parentserver
  expose:
    - "8000"
  links:
    - postgres:postgres
    - authserver:authserver
  volumes:
    - /usr/src/app
    - /usr/src/app/static
  env_file: .env
  environment:
    DEBUG: 'true'
  command: ./startup.sh

nginx:
  build: ./nginx/
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - /www/static
  volumes_from:    
    - parentserver
  links:
    - parentserver:parentserver
```

Are my volumes set wrong?

Would appreciate any feedback suggestions.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/44284993/4126114