# How to serve static files using Nginx and Django on Docker?

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-staticfiles

I've read some posts about this issue on StackOverflow already but couldn't fix my issue with them, as the title says I'm trying to serve static using django, nginx on docker.

At first I was getting an error saying **PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/static/admin'**. I've figured out that I had to change `STATIC_ROOT` from `STATIC_ROOT = '/static'` to `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`. Now `collectstatic` works on the Docker's Terminal but my webapp's static is still not working, I would like to understand why and fix it.

I've put the project on [Github](https://github.com/NuriddinK/Django-Docker) if you need any more infos.

**project.conf**

```
upstream web {  
  ip_hash;
  server web:8000;
}

server {
    location /static/ {    
        autoindex on;    
        alias /static/; 
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web/;
    }
    listen 8000;
    server_name localhost;
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'  
services:  
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nz01
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - /static:/static
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: dz01
    command: bash -c 'python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && gunicorn oqtor.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000'
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - /static:/static
    expose:
      - "8000"
    links:
      - redis
    ...
...
```

**Dockerfile :**

```
FROM python:latest
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

#ENV C_FORCE_ROOT true

ENV APP_USER myapp
ENV APP_ROOT /src
RUN mkdir /src;
RUN groupadd -r ${APP_USER} \
    && useradd -r -m \
    --home-dir ${APP_ROOT} \
    -s /usr/sbin/nologin \
    -g ${APP_USER} ${APP_USER}

WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}

RUN mkdir /config
ADD config/requirements.pip /config/
RUN pip install -r /config/requirements.pip

USER ${APP_USER}
ADD . ${APP_ROOT}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What is happening? What do you expect to happen? If there is an error message, it would help to provide that.

Comment: @MichaelMior No error logs, static won't load.

Comment: What does "won't load" mean? What happens when you try?

Comment: @MichaelMior Well, everything's showing up, there are texts, buttons but without styling, the images are also empty, the JS aren't here either, it's a white page with text only.

Comment: What happens if you try to directly access one of the resources that isn't loading?

Comment: @MichaelMior Error 404, the github is in the post, you can reproduce the problem by using `docker-compose build`, `docker-compose up -d`, `docker-compose up`.

Comment: could you show your django settings.py file?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/44284993/4126114

Comment: Did you get a solution to the issue. If yes, please share. I'm also stuck at it

Answer (score 0):

So you mentioned in the comments that you were getting a white page with text but no styling or javascript. In your browser there should be a way to show resources, normally available through right-clicking anywhere on the page. That should show you where the files are trying to be loaded from, which should simply allow you to point it to the right place.