# docker-compose nginx not found route for symfony assets

Tags: php, symfony, docker, nginx, docker-compose

There are similar questions in SO but not for this specific problem.

Tools: docker-compose 1.21.2; symfony 3.4; nginx 1.10.3

I have several decoupled containers ("Each container should have only one concern"). Everything works except for getting the assets of the symfony (3.4) application in the browser. **The defined routes work, templates are rendered correctly, only assets are the problem**. Besides using the same setup but serving in a dev machine locally (without containers) there are no problems.

With volumes it worked but I want to have them at production so as the docs indicate https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/#modify-your-compose-file-for-production a change you may need:

- Removing any volume bindings for application code, so that code stays inside the container and can’t be changed from outside

Facts:

- Inside the nginx container logs report 404 accesses but no errors.
- Inside the php-symfony container the prod logs show lines like `request.ERROR: Uncaught .... NotFoundException for "GET /css/main.css" at ...RouterListener.php {"exception": ".../NotFoundHttpException(code: 0) ... ResourceNotFoundException"} []`
- Checking dev in a browser `http://<host>:<port>/app_dev.php/css/main.css` nginx return 404.  (I made dev environment available externally)
- Checking dev in a browser for the route, example `http://<host>:<port>/app_dev.php/css` appears the Symfony Exception page **No route found for "GET /css"** with the same information `ResourceNotFoundException > NotFoundHttpException`
- Modifying access permissions to the `web` folder in the container `chmod -R a+rwx .../web` does not make a difference.

Relevant section **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "2"
services:
    site:
        ...
        working_dir:
            /var/www/html/site
    site_webserver:
        ...
        ports:
           - <port>:80
        depends_on:
           - site
        links:
           - site
```

Relevant section **nginx.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name "";
    root /var/www/html/site/web;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }  

    location ~ ^.*/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass lockate_site:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $document_root;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should have existing file /var/www/html/site/web/css/main.css! Do you have it?

Nginx config should not pass this request /css/main.css to PHP code. It should simply send existing file to browser.
I think you have this file, but on another path.

You shold correct nginx configuration for it, or put assets-files in /var/www/html/site/web/ directory

Comment: Ough! Maybe you forgot to mount assets dir into nginx container ?

Comment: Yes, the file exists "serving in a dev machine locally (without containers) there are no problems."; Why should asset dir be mounted? (Removing any volume bindings for application code, so that code stays inside the container and can’t be changed from outside https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/#modify-your-compose-file-for-production)

Answer (score 0):

Much more could be said but: the assets were blocked at the the php-fpm (symfony's) container.

In the container's file **www.conf** (in my case **/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf** ) check the directive `security.limit_extensions` and leave it like this

```
security.limit_extensions =
```

Note: I found it commented like this `;security.limit_extensions = .php .php3 .php4 .php5`

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is, nginx is searching the asset files in nginx container. After you install your assets using (app/console assets:install) they will copied into your php (symfony) container. You must link the assets them between containers. There is an answer to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44284993/6279901