# Docker-compose: How to share data between services without using named volumes or multi-stage builds

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Are there any ways to share data between containers. There is following docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
    app_build_prod:
        container_name: 'app'
        build:
            context: ../
            dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
            args:
                command: build:prod
    nginx:
        container_name: 'nginx'
        image: nginx:alpine
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        depends_on:
            - app_build_prod
```

Dockerfile content is:

```
FROM node:10-alpine as builder

## Installing missing packages, fixing git self signed certificate issue
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache bash git openssh && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && \
    git config --global http.sslVerify false

## Defigning app directory
WORKDIR /usr/app

## Copying files. Files listed in .dockerignore are omitted
COPY . .

## node_modules are on a separate intermediate image will prevent unnecessary npm installs at each build
RUN npm ci

## Declaring arguments and environment variables. Important to declara env var to consume them on run stage
ARG command=build:prod
ENV command=$command
ENTRYPOINT npm run ${command}
```

Tried with @Robert's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44284828/9590251), but couldn't make it work - app container crashes because of:

> EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir '/usr/app/dist
>   Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir '/usr/app/dist'

My assumption is that `/usr/app/dist` directory is mounted with read-only access, therefore when Angular attempt to remove it prior the build, it throws an error.

Need to send data following direction

```
app_build_prod:/usr/app/dist => nginx:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker Compose - Share named volume between multiple containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284484/docker-compose-share-named-volume-between-multiple-containers)

Comment: Nope. @Robert's approach crashes container.

Comment: Why do you say it can't be a multi-stage build?  That's the right Docker pattern for this.

Comment: @DavidMaze Dockerfile is just a builder. And nginx is conditional. For example we need to run nginx container only if app runs in `build:prod` mode. Furthermore there are gonna be 15 other docker-compose services (which passes different container build scrips: `test`, `track`, `watch`, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and change the sharing to use [multi-stage](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) build :

```
FROM alpine:latest AS builder
...build app_build_prod 

FROM nginx:alpine  
COPY --from=builder /usr/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

and change docker-compose to:

```
version: '3'
services:
    nginx:
        container_name: 'nginx'
        build:
             ...
        ports:
            - "80:80"
```

Comment: Thank you mate. I used to achieve this by using multi-stage builds, but I can't use it in this particular case, I need to find a way to use docker-compose only!

Comment: Can I ask Why app container crashes? I think it most be permission error check app_build_prod user

Comment: It crashes because of "EBUSY: resource busy or locked". Updated the question