# mount.cifs in Docker from another container requires privilege

Tags: docker, samba

My use case is a transcode farm that reads inputs from a Samba share and writes it to another.

Using `mount.cifs` in Docker requires both `SYS_ADMIN` and `DAC_READ_SEARCH` capabilities. I am able to use two hosts and run `smbd` on one host, and mount its share on another host. (Both `smbd` and `mount` are ran inside containers, just in different host.)

However, I cannot, using the same `mount` command, mount the Samba share on the host with the container that's running `smbd`.

EDIT: It works on Docker Desktop but fails in a Linux host. (With the same docker engine server version)

TL;DR the following Docker Compose fails UNLESS I give it privileged access.

Environments: Working on Docker for Mac, Not working on bare-metal Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.4 4.15.0-91-generic Docker 19.03.8 containerd 1.2.13), Not working on Hyper-V-virtualized Linux (Ubuntu 19.04 5.0.0-38-generic Docker 19.03.6 containerd 1.2.13)

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  samba:
    image: dperson/samba
    environment:
      TZ: 'EST5EDT'
    networks:
      - default
    ports:
      - "137/udp"
      - "138/udp"
      - "139/tcp"
      - "445/tcp"
    tmpfs:
      - /tmp
    restart: unless-stopped
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - /samba-data
    command: '/bin/bash -c "touch /samba-data/file.txt && samba.sh -s \"data;/samba-data\" -u \"bob;bob\" -p"'
  mounter:
    image: ubuntu
    command: '/bin/bash -c "apt update && apt install -y cifs-utils && mkdir /samba-data && mount -v -o username=bob,password=bob,vers=3.0,ro,port=445 //samba/data /samba-data"'
    tty: true
#   privileged: true
    cap_add:
      - SYS_ADMIN
      - DAC_READ_SEARCH
networks:
  default:
```

My questions,

1. Why is privileged required when running on the same Docker host?
2. Can I make it more restrictive (by giving it only what it needs)?

Comment: just realized that the downvoter might be thinking that this belongs to ServerFault. hmm.. should it?

Answer (score 2):

Is there anything in your use case, requiring the mount to be done inside the container ? How about letting docker handle the mount ?

In your example, you are starting a container to expose a samba share, and another one to read from it. How about simply binding both containers to the same docker volume (i.e. define a named volume at the top level of your docker-compose, and use it in both services) ? That's the usual way to share a mount between container, and this doesn't require privileges or open ports. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284484/docker-compose-share-named-volume-between-multiple-containers) for example.

If this "shared folder" must be CIFS (because in real life it's not a samba container, but a Windows server ?), you can define the volume with a `volume-driver` parameter pointing to a [docker volume plugin](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/legacy_plugins/) which supports CIFS, such as [this one](https://github.com/ContainX/docker-volume-netshare) or [this other one](https://github.com/trajano/docker-volume-plugins/tree/master/cifs-volume-plugin). Your "mounter" container would start with the CIFS share already mounted. No need to mount from inside the container, hence no need for a privileged container or extended caps.

Comment: I’m hoping to orchestrate this through container orchestration software. But I am open to using a volume driver as Microsoft have SMB plugin for K8s. It works in Docker for Mac and Windows but not bare-metal Ubuntu server, I guess I just want to know why. Thanks for the suggestion though :)