# Celery task can't access volume file in docker

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, celery

Admin page can get access to the image file saved in database but Celery task can't get access to that image file and shows error `FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')`.
**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services: 
    app: &app
        build: 
            context: .
        ports: 
            - "8000:8000"
        volumes: 
            - ./backend:/backend
        command: >
            sh -c "python manage.py wait_for_db &&
                    python manage.py migrate &&
                    python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
        environment: 
            - SECRET_KEY=mysecretkey
            - DB_HOST=db
            - DB_NAME=election
            - DB_USER=postgres
            - DB_PASS=supersecretpassword
        depends_on: 
            - db
            - redis
    db:
        image: postgres:12-alpine
        environment: 
            - POSTGRES_DB=election
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=supersecretpassword
        volumes:
            - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
    redis:
        image: redis:6-alpine
    celery:
        <<: *app
        command: celery -A app worker -l INFO
        ports: []
        volumes: 
            - ./backend:/backend
        depends_on:
            - app
            - redis
            - db
volumes: 
    postgresql_data:
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.8 

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1


# Face-recognition model
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y --fix-missing \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    gfortran \
    git \
    wget \
    curl \
    graphicsmagick \
    libgraphicsmagick1-dev \
    libatlas-base-dev \
    libavcodec-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libgtk2.0-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    liblapack-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    pkg-config \
    python3-dev \
    python3-numpy \
    software-properties-common \
    zip \
    # web3
    libssl-dev \
    # QR code
    zbar-tools \
    libzbar-dev \
    && apt-get autoremove \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
        
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /backend
WORKDIR /backend
COPY ./backend /backend

RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/media
RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/static

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash user
RUN chown -R user:user /vol/
RUN chmod -R 755 /vol/web
USER user
```

**Celery task**

```py
from celery import shared_task
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

from django.core.mail import message

from core.models import Profile
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

from time import sleep
import os

@shared_task
def id_generated(profile_id):
    """
    Task to send an e-mail with ID image attached.
    """
    profile = Profile.objects.get(id=profile_id)
    print(profile.id_card)
    subject = 'ID card.'
    print(profile.id_card.path)
    message = render_to_string('mails/id_card_html.html')
    email = EmailMessage(subject,
                         message,
                         'admin@myshop.com',
                         [profile.user.email])
    image = profile.id_card.open().read()
    email.attach(image)
    email.add_header('Content-ID', '<embed_image>')
    email.send()
```

**And Error is**

```
celery_1  | [2020-09-28 11:35:28,604: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task core.tasks.id_generated[b11d5f6d-0b7c-4e97-a548-1787ac49c80a] raised unexpected: FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
celery_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
celery_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 409, in trace_task
celery_1  |     R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
celery_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 701, in __protected_call__
celery_1  |     return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
celery_1  |   File "/backend/core/tasks.py", line 33, in id_generated
celery_1  |     image = profile.id_card.open().read()
celery_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 74, in open
celery_1  |     self.file = self.storage.open(self.name, mode)
celery_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 36, in open
celery_1  |     return self._open(name, mode)
celery_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 231, in _open
celery_1  |     return File(open(self.path(name), mode))
celery_1  | FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/vol/web/media/uploads/user/2/card/2f6552ec-d86c-4a4b-886e-923bf9d21742.jpg'
```

> Image file can be read anywhere except from celery task, Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

In Docker compose you need to share the volume between both containers ie. celery and app.
Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44284993/2138792

Comment: Thanks, but not fixes the problems.