# How to use a shared volume in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volume

Docker documentation is unclear about how to share a volume between containers. I don't want to have a bind volume for each container. I would like to have one volume defined and named, shared by multiple docker-compose containers. Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
services:
    service-1:
        ....
        volumes:
            - volume:folder_in_container

    service-2:
        ....
        volumes:
            - volume:folder_in_container

volumes:
     volume:
```

I think you will be helped here :) [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284484/docker-compose-share-named-volume-between-multiple-containers)