# Docker volume from host directory with docker-compose

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

Is it possible to link the directory from the project where the docker-compose file is located?
I want to link the folder where the input data for the program to work in the container and also the output data that another program can read

Comment: Did you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284484/docker-compose-share-named-volume-between-multiple-containers)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the volume in the host. Map that volume from your container to that volume and do the same from other container to share the files.