# Docker volume -v flag works but docker-compose volumes doesnt work

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volumes

I am trying to get a containers git folder into my local folder. (bind containers folder with my computers local folder) as in images description when I do like this

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 8001:8001 -v $(pwd):/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/.niogit:Z -d --name jbpm-workbench jboss/business-central-workbench-showcase:latest
```

everything works as expected. But if I try this in docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.9"

services:   business-central:
    image: jboss/business-central-workbench-showcase:latest
    network_mode: default
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 8001:8001
    volumes:
      - ./git:/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/.niogit:Z
```

it does not work.

when I inspect containers docker run one says

```
[
{
    "Id": "050a4dceb241d04f5e92d1d963a73646e1a8559ff3094c1705229bd2ad22859a",
    "Created": "2021-06-08T09:11:04.082653292Z",
    "Path": "./start_business-central-wb.sh",
    "Args": [],
    "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 62316,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2021-06-08T09:11:04.423834376Z",
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "Image": "sha256:a84b58b28277164c45aaef1a44a5070e883e5ae7d1732164af6694fca9313479",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/050a4dceb241d04f5e92d1d963a73646e1a8559ff3094c1705229bd2ad22859a/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/050a4dceb241d04f5e92d1d963a73646e1a8559ff3094c1705229bd2ad22859a/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/050a4dceb241d04f5e92d1d963a73646e1a8559ff3094c1705229bd2ad22859a/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/050a4dceb241d04f5e92d1d963a73646e1a8559ff3094c1705229bd2ad22859a/050a4dceb241d04f5e92d1d963a73646e1a8559ff3094c1705229bd2ad22859a-json.log",
    "Name": "/jbpm-workbench",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "overlay2",
    "Platform": "linux",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
    "ExecIDs": null,
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": [
            "/home/bahadir/Documents/Projects/kosgeb-engine:/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/.niogit:Z"
        ],
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "NetworkMode": "default",
        "PortBindings": {
            "8001/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "8001"
                }
            ],
            "8080/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                }
            ]
        },
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "no",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "AutoRemove": false,
        "VolumeDriver": "",
        "VolumesFrom": null,
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "CgroupnsMode": "host",
        "Dns": [],
        "DnsOptions": [],
        "DnsSearch": [],
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "IpcMode": "private",
        "Cgroup": "",
        "Links": null,
        "OomScoreAdj": 0,
        "PidMode": "",
        "Privileged": false,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "UTSMode": "",
        "UsernsMode": "",
        "ShmSize": 67108864,
        "Runtime": "runc",
        "ConsoleSize": [
            0,
            0
        ],
        "Isolation": "",
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "Memory": 0,
        "NanoCpus": 0,
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
        "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
        "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "Devices": [],
        "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
        "DeviceRequests": null,
        "KernelMemory": 0,
        "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "MemorySwappiness": null,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "PidsLimit": null,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "CpuCount": 0,
        "CpuPercent": 0,
        "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
        "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
        "MaskedPaths": [
            "/proc/asound",
            "/proc/acpi",
            "/proc/kcore",
            "/proc/keys",
            "/proc/latency_stats",
            "/proc/timer_list",
            "/proc/timer_stats",
            "/proc/sched_debug",
            "/proc/scsi",
            "/sys/firmware"
        ],
        "ReadonlyPaths": [
            "/proc/bus",
            "/proc/fs",
            "/proc/irq",
            "/proc/sys",
            "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
        ]
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Data": {
            "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/acb0b2ead431d53fa4bb06a663b3dda5274d1b9bf770e47da952173c5f574a58-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d6e0af68bcecebe63a2084109e8ea402323b5639ad4930e3810404e1a004b1b0/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/11503e1a3cbe3ccaf2a08bd53163fad56568e125c4315f8f11ed26b348c6a296/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/452b79bce41d21a121fe1d517b8f41e29b63943cc880697bf78372e3e3f4dede/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6da58405868eee65c7e8fc5a96133dc3960fa02ef1e6e38fb341ca58d05d943d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/918f9536c42ee86146011fdc95cb1fa496b6c787849719c621764e178e78127e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9bf60d043c0e84a69a321017b19a4d89ac3e242207ba00c7dc685e30d7e962bf/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ebd7aceb50c16e9d98d947efbda24518187019fc77f86d867a2f173a3a5260f0/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/aa89eb5308ae3a52abe04fd56bc8485d77d31ee87098e19808dcfbf4c4bdc786/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7e65422f205cffb53ff2e8726f49c2e72392b72b4765081bae3a0a8eb3021fc6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/de58fc4c63bfefd3262d122af87c5f2ef855aa13c6b9e96ee2dfd91e54292ede/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d5cbc322dcecb6404123d32c28b00b0b8e57eb69d575f27a223a3e87975a55c0/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c83b9acd413abf540a9d00708a8d3ad7533e7a374788a0950b0f151ddb7c41d6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5860d1bf949d13bf2fa6d8d6d0b920952096f49ea53813b6cc62c6873832d514/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4c588e89452e1b0303a5cc60e7c40faffe4c8d2149d6c202fd98e796b20832bb/diff",
            "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/acb0b2ead431d53fa4bb06a663b3dda5274d1b9bf770e47da952173c5f574a58/merged",
            "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/acb0b2ead431d53fa4bb06a663b3dda5274d1b9bf770e47da952173c5f574a58/diff",
            "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/acb0b2ead431d53fa4bb06a663b3dda5274d1b9bf770e47da952173c5f574a58/work"
        },
        "Name": "overlay2"
    },
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/home/bahadir/Documents/Projects/kosgeb-engine",
            "Destination": "/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/.niogit",
            "Mode": "Z",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        }
    ],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "050a4dceb241",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "jboss",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "8001/tcp": {},
            "8080/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java",
            "WILDFLY_VERSION=19.1.0.Final",
            "WILDFLY_SHA1=6883125745a62b598659ea351f5b1706aff53955",
            "JBOSS_HOME=/opt/jboss/wildfly",
            "LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=true",
            "JBOSS_BIND_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0",
            "KIE_REPOSITORY=https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss",
            "KIE_VERSION=7.54.0.Final",
            "KIE_CLASSIFIER=wildfly19",
            "KIE_CONTEXT_PATH=business-central",
            "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx2048m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8",
            "KIE_SERVER_PROFILE=standalone"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "./start_business-central-wb.sh"
        ],
        "Image": "jboss/business-central-workbench-showcase:latest",
        "Volumes": null,
        "WorkingDir": "/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin",
        "Entrypoint": null,
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {
            "org.label-schema.build-date": "20181205",
            "org.label-schema.license": "GPLv2",
            "org.label-schema.name": "CentOS Base Image",
            "org.label-schema.schema-version": "1.0",
            "org.label-schema.vendor": "CentOS"
        }
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "231baa83449352957b8f7b6469defbb410ae1455dd06c990f9fe75483ade72ed",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "8001/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "8001"
                },
                {
                    "HostIp": "::",
                    "HostPort": "8001"
                }
            ],
            "8080/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                },
                {
                    "HostIp": "::",
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                }
            ]
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/231baa834493",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "7e18648624c81b5f89cb7d959c7db4879cca7d5a56c16fba081112e88fceb377",
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
        "Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": null,
                "NetworkID": "88ea0e8bc4569ba79ff1a31ec42828996a32784c7069fc7c31ef1e3cc589fc31",
                "EndpointID": "7e18648624c81b5f89cb7d959c7db4879cca7d5a56c16fba081112e88fceb377",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "DriverOpts": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

]

docker compose one says

```
[
    {
        "Id": "a332ff863902ef097abd84fc48e2a842a89e2ffbb9f9bdc6dcee3374d0a8bf49",
        "Created": "2021-06-08T09:06:37.889000317Z",
        "Path": "./start_business-central-wb.sh",
        "Args": [],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 63252,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2021-06-08T09:13:17.064498858Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2021-06-08T09:08:55.784957587Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:a84b58b28277164c45aaef1a44a5070e883e5ae7d1732164af6694fca9313479",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/a332ff863902ef097abd84fc48e2a842a89e2ffbb9f9bdc6dcee3374d0a8bf49/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/a332ff863902ef097abd84fc48e2a842a89e2ffbb9f9bdc6dcee3374d0a8bf49/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/a332ff863902ef097abd84fc48e2a842a89e2ffbb9f9bdc6dcee3374d0a8bf49/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/a332ff863902ef097abd84fc48e2a842a89e2ffbb9f9bdc6dcee3374d0a8bf49/a332ff863902ef097abd84fc48e2a842a89e2ffbb9f9bdc6dcee3374d0a8bf49-json.log",
        "Name": "/kosgeb-engine_business-central_1",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/home/bahadir/Documents/Projects/kosgeb-engine/git:/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/.niogit:Z"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "8001/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "8001"
                    }
                ],
                "8080/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "8080"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": [],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "host",
            "Dns": null,
            "DnsOptions": null,
            "DnsSearch": null,
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a38b6370ce4a56fa04b2eba071d0229a324484a76cd84cbd9cb2f199040aba92-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d6e0af68bcecebe63a2084109e8ea402323b5639ad4930e3810404e1a004b1b0/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/11503e1a3cbe3ccaf2a08bd53163fad56568e125c4315f8f11ed26b348c6a296/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/452b79bce41d21a121fe1d517b8f41e29b63943cc880697bf78372e3e3f4dede/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6da58405868eee65c7e8fc5a96133dc3960fa02ef1e6e38fb341ca58d05d943d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/918f9536c42ee86146011fdc95cb1fa496b6c787849719c621764e178e78127e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9bf60d043c0e84a69a321017b19a4d89ac3e242207ba00c7dc685e30d7e962bf/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ebd7aceb50c16e9d98d947efbda24518187019fc77f86d867a2f173a3a5260f0/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/aa89eb5308ae3a52abe04fd56bc8485d77d31ee87098e19808dcfbf4c4bdc786/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7e65422f205cffb53ff2e8726f49c2e72392b72b4765081bae3a0a8eb3021fc6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/de58fc4c63bfefd3262d122af87c5f2ef855aa13c6b9e96ee2dfd91e54292ede/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d5cbc322dcecb6404123d32c28b00b0b8e57eb69d575f27a223a3e87975a55c0/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c83b9acd413abf540a9d00708a8d3ad7533e7a374788a0950b0f151ddb7c41d6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5860d1bf949d13bf2fa6d8d6d0b920952096f49ea53813b6cc62c6873832d514/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4c588e89452e1b0303a5cc60e7c40faffe4c8d2149d6c202fd98e796b20832bb/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a38b6370ce4a56fa04b2eba071d0229a324484a76cd84cbd9cb2f199040aba92/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a38b6370ce4a56fa04b2eba071d0229a324484a76cd84cbd9cb2f199040aba92/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a38b6370ce4a56fa04b2eba071d0229a324484a76cd84cbd9cb2f199040aba92/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/home/bahadir/Documents/Projects/kosgeb-engine/git",
                "Destination": "/opt/jboss/wilfly/bin/.niogit",
                "Mode": "Z",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "a332ff863902",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "jboss",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "8001/tcp": {},
                "8080/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java",
                "WILDFLY_VERSION=19.1.0.Final",
                "WILDFLY_SHA1=6883125745a62b598659ea351f5b1706aff53955",
                "JBOSS_HOME=/opt/jboss/wildfly",
                "LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=true",
                "JBOSS_BIND_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0",
                "KIE_REPOSITORY=https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss",
                "KIE_VERSION=7.54.0.Final",
                "KIE_CLASSIFIER=wildfly19",
                "KIE_CONTEXT_PATH=business-central",
                "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx2048m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8",
                "KIE_SERVER_PROFILE=standalone"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "./start_business-central-wb.sh"
            ],
            "Image": "jboss/business-central-workbench-showcase:latest",
            "Volumes": {
                "/opt/jboss/wilfly/bin/.niogit": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "f59ac4f02be4567f3eb5c811caa332ad6515fc9d319fa5469ef6adfe4f99a5ab",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "kosgeb-engine",
                "com.docker.compose.project.config_files": "docker-compose.yml",
                "com.docker.compose.project.working_dir": "/home/bahadir/Documents/Projects/kosgeb-engine",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "business-central",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "1.29.2",
                "org.label-schema.build-date": "20181205",
                "org.label-schema.license": "GPLv2",
                "org.label-schema.name": "CentOS Base Image",
                "org.label-schema.schema-version": "1.0",
                "org.label-schema.vendor": "CentOS"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "de92ff5ea51180722b17313c9225e57de2b6b61e2786a3758cdccbc911556c75",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "8001/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "8001"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "8001"
                    }
                ],
                "8080/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "8080"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "8080"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/de92ff5ea511",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "f8e4ed72e4390995e34790b6a26a2c93557a71f0a9189e0b90f642dd77e2d772",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "88ea0e8bc4569ba79ff1a31ec42828996a32784c7069fc7c31ef1e3cc589fc31",
                    "EndpointID": "f8e4ed72e4390995e34790b6a26a2c93557a71f0a9189e0b90f642dd77e2d772",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're bind-mounting different directories: your `docker run` command bind-mounts the current directory, but the Compose setup bind-mounts `./git`.

Comment: @DavidMaze tried usind full path as     
volumes:
      - /home/bahadir/Documents/Projects/kosgeb-engine/git:/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/.niogit:Z

didnt changed the result. any other idea sir I am kid of stuck :( ?

Comment: In the working `docker run` command you don't have the `.../git` subdirectory in the host path; try removing that in the corresponding Compose setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind volumes using long syntax like shown in [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#short-syntax-3).

so your volumes should look like this:

```
volumes:
  - type: bind
    source: ./git
    target: /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/.niogit
    volume:
      nocopy: true
```

you can also take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284484/docker-compose-share-named-volume-between-multiple-containers).