# DRF and Celery: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, celery

This works fine on my local deployment but on the cloud deployement it does not.

```
with open(file_path, "wb+") as fp:
    for chunk in file:
        fp.write(chunk)

result = upload.delay(name, file_path)
```

In a different file:

```
@shared_task
def upload(name, file_path):

    path = Path(path_tmp)
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        do something
```

The error is

> Not a path /mediafiles/rawfiles/file.png",
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

When I navigate in the docker to -> `/mediafiles/rawfiles`, the file is there and has a size.

I am using DRF -> Celery -> Django.

Can someone help why the cloud deployment is not able to find the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delegate task to celery worker with `@shared_task` and try to get access to the filesystem, it try to get this file on the worker machine.
So you need to execute this task on machine with a file or copy target file to worker machine.

Comment: Thank you so much for this clarification! This explains alot. Do you have any suggestions on how to copy that file from Django to the Celery Worker?

Comment: maybe you need to use something like `s3` or `minio` for storing file. So celery worker get file by path from it. I think you should look in this direction.

Comment: thanks you pointed me in the right direction, my question should have been ``how to share volumes between celery and django` and found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284484/docker-compose-share-named-volume-between-multiple-containers/44284993#44284993

Answer (score 1):

I add **workdir** to the start cmd, then it works well.

```bash
celery -A tasks --workdir=. worker ...
```

Hope that helps.