# Difficulty Accessing Files Mounted from One Docker Container to Another in Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Question:
I have a Docker Compose configuration with two containers, "hop" and "py_env" (Python environment). I'm trying to mount the "/opt/hop" folder from the "hop" container to the "py_env" container, but I'm unable to find the files in the Python environment.
I can only see the hop3 folder (see code below)
On the other hand, when I mount the "/bin" folder to "/test1," I can access the files without any issues.

Here's my Docker Compose YAML:

```
name: production

services:
  hop:
    # ... (hop container configuration)
    volumes:
      - C:/data-pipelines:/files 
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 8180:8180

  py_env:
    container_name: py_env
    hostname: py_env
    build:
      context: ./docker_python_server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - hop
    ports:
      - 5550:80
    volumes:
      - /opt/hop:/opt/hop3
      - /bin:/test1
```

Why can't I find the files from "/opt/hop" in the "py_env" container, and how can I successfully mount and access these files between containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Docker there are primarily two types of volumes, named volumes and bind mounts, but both essentially serve to allow containers to store files in some location on the host (the machine on which the containers are running) or use files that already existed on the host. That said, note that the `py_env` container volumes are of type bind mount and reference the `/opt/hop` and `/bin` directories on your host, not the `hop` container. If you want both containers to be able to access the same files, you need to use [shared volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284484/docker-compose-share-named-volume-between-multiple-containers) (here you will find examples using named volumes and bind mounts).